# How to force hibernate to search for values with different patterns?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

First of all, question is not about ignoring white spaces at the beginning or end of the strings so it is not a duplicate.

I have a mobile field in database that its values are in different formats such as xxx xxx xxx, xxxxxxxxx, x xxx xxx xx etc, how can I make hibernate criteria to ignore the patterns of strings?

**For example**, lets say the number in database is 344 555 666

```
 344555666  is failed 
 344 555 666 is failed 
 344 is true (first three digits that do not have space in database!)
```

However, there is no doubt that all numbers are provided and all aforementioned values should return 344 555 666 as their results.

**Another example** would be as following:

Lets say a user searches for all phone numbers that includes 12345; then DB returns following results 12345678, 12345987 and 12345768 now I need to format these three numbers that are returned by DB before showing to the user.

**Code**

```
...
private String mobile;
....
```

**Hibernate**

```
.add(Restrictions.ilike("user.mobile", number);
```

**PVR's answer** is useful,but how about if in future I needed to add a new format like XXX-XXX-XXX or X-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX ? Please also note **there is only one field** that user uses to enter the search value.

Comment: IMHO, you attack the problem by the wrong side. Even if you find a way, every search will require a full database scan. You should try to normalize the data in the database at write time, or at least use a batch processing o re-normalize it regurlaly. You search could the make use of indexes and the app would be much more responsive.

Comment: @SergeBallesta what do you mean by app would be much more responsive ? how to normalize it ? there is only one column called mobile and no two users would have same mobile numbers.

Comment: Normalization may not be the correct word (english is not my first language). I meant you should write all mobile numbers in same format (eg :123456789) in database. All your search queries will be simpler and so (a little) faster. But a select query using indexes may be order of magnitude faster than without indexes. And you need your mobile numbers to all have same format to properly index them.

Comment: @SergeBallesta ok got you, but how to do the rest? I mean how to show them in their associated pattern? should I retrieve them all and format them before presenting them to user?

Answer (score 1):

Try using following..

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(
user.mobile, number, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

**Edit :**

I meant that if the format of the no. in the database can only be one amongst XXX XXX XXXX / XXXXXXXXXX then we need to write a specific logic which checks both of the formats availability in database.

**number1 : in format of XXX XXX XXXX
number2 : in format of XXXXXXXXXX**

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.ilike(
    user.mobile, number1, MatchMode.ANYWHERE),(Restrictions.ilike(
    user.mobile, number2, MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
```

Comment: It is still showing the same results as explained in the questions.

Comment: Is the format of storing the no. in database can only be two ie. XXX XXX XXXX / XXXXXXXXXX ??

Comment: Kindly have a look at the Edit Section

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how about if in future I needed to add a new format like XXX-XXX-XXX or X-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX ? Please also note there is only one field that user may enter values in different formats.

Comment: In that case, you have to restrict one format in your database and you can accept as many formats you want from user-input. That should be the practice. Or if the above is not feasible, you need to add Restrictions.or for every format you introduce.

Comment: What do you mean by using Restrictions.or ? lets say user enters 1 818 222 2222 and the other time types 222 2222 or the other time types 2 222222, how can I include all this formats in the database using MatchMode? Please note, there is ONLY ONE field that is used by user to enter the value so using number1, number2 etc as you did in your answer is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Facing such problem, I usually reverse it. Currently, you have in a single column of your database (`mobile`) values in different formats (*xxx xxx xxx, xxxxxxxxx, x xxx xxx xx etc.*) and it is hard to make search on that column.

You should still allow input of mobile numbers in all those formats, but carefully rewrite them in *one single format* say `12345679` before writing them in database. This way that *reformatting* occurs only when inserting new records or on updates, and I assume you will have much more read accesses than write ones.

If you allready have records in your database, you should considere using a batch to transform them in one single operation .

Once you have only one format, you can put an index on the column as it could speed select queries by orders of magnitude as soon as you have thousands of records.

When you want to do a search, allow any format for user input of what they want, and apply same transformation that you apply on insert. For example if a user presents `123 456 789` or `123-456-789` or any of your accepted format, in your code for search transform it in `123456789` and do you query with that value (using the index ...)

From user point of view, you still allow he to present input as he wants, and simply the responses may come faster. The only drawback is that you will display not the value he entered but a *standardized* version of it.

From your point of view (as the programmer) you get something simpler to write and to maintain with less stress on database.

Comment: thats good but the only problem is that when I want to show let's say a list of 1000 customers, I need to format their mobile numbers using Google library before am I right? I reckon that affects the performance, is there any way to avoid performance issues in that case?

Comment: @Jack I do not understand where the problem is when showing a list : you show the values as they are stored in your database. You only reformat the input value for an insert, an update or a search.

Comment: You've got me wrong, lets say a user enters the mobile number as 12345 (a partial, not formatted number) then DB returns following results 12345678, 12345987 and 12345768 now I need to format these three numbers that are returned by DB before showing to the user.

Comment: @Jack Sorry I didn't understand ... what I meant is if user enter 123-45, you query with `... LIKE '12345%'` (but with a prepared statement ...) **using the index**. But I advice you not to show a list of 1000 values in one single response but rather use pagination.

Comment: Thats a good idea, by index do you mean having index on that column of DB?

Answer (score 0):

did you try  [Projections.sqlProjection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#sqlProjection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%5B%5D%29)

You can use replace REPLACE(mobile, ' ') inside

Comment: what do you mean by replace and sqlprojection? I reckon sql projection is used to specify the fields of result,

Answer (score 0):

> I know this is an answer that could eat up your db resources, you can
>   test it and check if it matches your need.

I've done phone number formatting before, but, the solution you are looking for could be difficult, if you have to search using regex I'll construct a regex in the code and search in the db. (Oracle has regex_like function, you may want to use that instead of ilike of hibernate)

eg phone number from client +333 555 9999, phone number in db: +3 33 555 9999

**Construct the following regex based on what client sends:**

```
/+(\s-.)*3(\s-.)*3(\s-.)*3(\s-.)*5(\s-.)*5(\s-.)*5(\s-.)*9(\s-.)*9(\s-.)*9(\s-.)*9(\s-.\d\w)*/
```

What you are saying is there could be many (.) dots may (\s) spaces many (-) hiphens in a phone number trailing with many(.\s-\d\w) (eg: x234 or ext2342)

Comment: It seems it would be a complex task to do, how did you do your previous tasks of phone number formatting ? my database is mysql not oracle

Comment: The regex i've done is a client validation, client takes care of everything, it is differant than your senario. Users saves what ever he likes, just before the data is presented, it will be formatted as per the country he is located in.

Comment: then in my case what would be the best option ? I am using mysql not oracle. Should I keep them all non-formatted and format them before showing to users?

Answer (score 0):

As per your conversation with PVR, it seems like the format of the phone number can be anything. 
Hibernate framework is based on patterns. It cannot handle any format on its own. 
Its advisable to not include the phone number based criteria in Hibernate. You must execute your entire criteria query without the phone number and thereafter you must have java logic for filtering rest of the results.

However, the best solution is make your design more solid. Adding constraint on the format of the phone is the best practice. You can consider adding a validation on format of phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own Criterion by implementing the Criterion interface.
In your toSqlString method just use the replace function of your database. AFAIK `replace(str, needle, replacement)` is a SQL99 standard function so it should work in todays dbms.